# What is the purpose of options.dup in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Browsing through the Rails codebase I find numerous references to options.dup.

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  require 'builder' unless defined?(Builder)
  options = options.dup
  ....
end
```

Obviously options.dup is duplicating the options hash, but why would you wish to do this in this context?

Comment: It seems that no search has done before asking this question. You should always try to get the answer on your own and if you don't find an answer then you should ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: i searched and i dont found answer. That is reason i`m asking here

Comment: This is a sensible question, unfairly marked down due to the authors use of English as a second language. Edited for clarity and voted up. Please try to be a little more friendly people, we're Rubyists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dup` clones an object.  When you pass an object to a method, anything that changes the internal state of that object will be reflected in the calling scope.  For example, try this code:

```
def replace_two(options)
  options[:two] = "hi there"
end

options = { one: "foo", two: "bar" }
replace_two(options)
puts options[:two]
```

That will print `hi there`, because `replace_two()` modified the hash contents.

If you want to avoid changing the passed-in `options`, you can  call `.dup` on it, and then any changes made to the clone won't be reflected in the calling scope:

```
def replace_two(options)
  options = options.dup
  options[:two] = "hi there"
end

options = { one: "foo", two: "bar" }
replace_two(options)
puts options[:two]
```

Will print `bar`.  This is a common pattern that follows the [Principle of Least Astonishment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment) .  In Ruby, methods that modify their arguments are usually named with a `!` suffix to alert the user that they are destructive/modifying actions.  The non-`dup` version of the method should have been called `replace_two!` to indicate this side-effect.

Comment: `dup` is just a shallow copy, as @denis-bu stated.  It won't clone nested inner objects, just the first-level internals.

Comment: Thank you, very well and detailed explain

Answer (score 5):

`dup` creates a shallow copy of an object. It's ruby core stuff. Since in ruby objects like Hash and Array are passed by reference, when you change object inside of a function this will change original object. If this is not desired behavior - you create a copy... So that code does.

See [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)

**UPDATE**

One more thing. Since object are passed by reference, `options = options.dup` will assign to `options` variable reference to newly created copy. Reference to original object is lost inside `to_xml`. But it is still probably referenced in code that invoke `to_xml`